# Django Admin: Show only some objects in ManyToMany field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have relatively simple data model with `User`, `Group` and `Task`. Each group has its own tasks and users. Users can be only assigned to one group.

Tasks belong to groups and each task has `manyToMany` field for users, so multiple users can have the same task assigned.

In my admin when assigning users to task it shows all created users, I want it to **only show users from the same group as the task.**

What would be the best approach?

I have checked available customization options for `admin.ModelAdmin` but haven't found anything related to my problem.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `formfield_for_manytomany`

the `formfield_for_manytomany` method can be overridden to change the default formfield for a many to many field

in your case change your `admin.py` to :

```
class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_object(self, request, object_id, s):
        # Hook obj for use in formfield_for_manytomany
        self.obj = super(TaskAdmin, self).get_object(request, object_id)
        # print ("Got object:", self.obj)
        return self.obj


    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "user":
            kwargs["queryset"] = User.objects.filter(task=self.obj)
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Task, TaskAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks this looks something like I need but I have no idea how to access the current `Task` object opened to filter whether its `Group` is same as user's group.

Comment: there is a get_object() method in django you can get the Task object

Comment: Thanks, I found this method but apparently it does not work all the time and is undocumented... But if there is no other way..

Comment: get_object() is the only way i think

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the model admin using a method: [formfield_for_manytomany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany)

```
class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "users":
            # Filter your users below as per your condition
            kwargs["queryset"] = Users.objects.filter()
        return super(TaskAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks this looks something like I need but I have no idea how to access the current `Task` object opened to filter whether its `Group` is same as user's group.